# How to programmatically trigger a leaflet popup via the img of the marker

Tags: leaflet

I have a use case for leaflet where i need to have a list of POI on the left, and a leaflet map showing markers for those POI on the right.

If i click on a marker on the map, i highlight the POI in the list, this works fine.

However, i also want to do the reverse: if i click on the POI in the list, center the map on the marker for that POI and open it's popup.

I reckoned that if i could get the right img for the marker and then trigger a clickevent on it via JS, that should work.  But that fails to trigger the popup.  I can't find anything in the docs, blogposts or stackoverflow.

Anybody with any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i can do this by ensuring i have an array of the markers, then select the marker tied to the list and call the openPopup() method on it.

Found the answer here: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/180#issuecomment-18669817